# how to insert data in array inside form input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array and it has some data in it. This array contains id, firstname, lastname, email, phone. I also have five form input elements. Now I want to add data in array in these elements. For example, ID should be inserted in ID form field, name should be inserted in name input element etc. how can I achieve this?

here is my code

```
insert_data_in_form: function(data) {
    var form = $("#dataform");
    var form_arr = new Array();

    form.each(function(i) {
        var form_el = form.children("input[type='textfield']");
        form_arr.push(form_el);
        console.log(data.length);
        //for(var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            form_el.val(data[i]);
        //}
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the values in data array are in the same order as they are in the form then you can do this

```
insert_data_in_form: function(data) {
    var formElems = $("#dataform input[type='text']");
    formElems.each(function(i,elem) {
        $(this).val(data[i]);
        // or even better use the following faster way 
        // if they are always text boxes
        // this.value = data[i];
    });
}
```

**Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/AJhEW/

**UPDATE (Alternate Way):**

You can also achieve this using `Implicit Looping` with this `.val(function(index,val)` variant of the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function like this

```
var insert_data_in_form =  function(data) {
    var formElems = $("#dataform input[type='text']");
    formElems.val(function(i) {
       return data[i];
    });
};
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/AJhEW/2/

Answer (score 0):

el -> arr:

```
form_arr[form_el.attr('name')] = form_el.val();
```

arr -> el:

```
form_el.val(form_arr[form_el.attr('name')]);
```